# detection the selfish node Using awk File

Tags: awk

I am working on detection the selfish node based on this equation Using awk File : (Node Communication Ratio) NCR= ((Get Route Request-(Get Route Request-Reply Route Request))/Get Route Request)*100

Is the code correct?

````
BEGIN { 
    ReqCounter=0;
    RepCounter=0;
    NCRCounter=0;
   Normalcounter=0;

} 
    
{action=$1; 
node=$5
 
if(action == "s" || action == "r" || action == "f") 
{ 
 if(($61 == "REQUEST"))
    ReqCounter++;
if(($57 == "REPLY"))
    RepCounter++;
 
} 
}
END { 
    NCR= ((ReqCounter-(ReqCounter-RepCounter))/ReqCounter)*100;
 

    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
 if(NCR <= 30)
    NCRCounter++;  
else
  Normalcounter++;

    
    }
printf "number of nodes:%d \n", i;
    printf "REQUEST Count:%d \n", ReqCounter;
    printf "REPLY Count:%d \n", RepCounter;
        printf "number of selfish nodes:%d \n", NCRCounter;
        printf "number of normal nodes:%d \n", Normalcounter;
    
}
```
````

Comment: Net simulator NS-2 : As usual, an analyzing awk script must be a match for the trace.tr . ... If you want an answer, then the file.tcl or the trace.tr must be available.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Did you test the code you wrote? Did it appear to function correctly?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IX9dz7PJIR3S_g8_l89ecsFhRY6fX_vj?usp=sharing

Comment: It always shows me that all the nodes are selfish.. I don't know if the problem is from the awk file or from the tcl file